# Parrot OS: "Failed to start Light Display Manager"

Tags: boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine, lightdm, parrotsec

i have recently installed Parrot OS on virtualBox, the installation was successful but as the system started booting, it stopped showing "Failed to start Light Display Manager".

here is the `systemctl status lightdm` :

[image]

Any idea how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post the result of `journalctl -b -u lightdm.service` after failing to start lightdm?

Answer (score -1):

Starting Light Display Manager...
Oct 01 19:07:12 dell systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 01 19:07:12 dell systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 01 19:07:12 dell systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
Oct 01 19:07:12 dell systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 01 19:07:12 dell systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.

My issue

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/390052)